# How do we create a range of dates using Generate_Series or CTE in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, common-table-expression, azure-synapse

How do we get GENERATE_SERIES to work for Synapse??
If you try running the query SELECT * FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1,10,1) as a simple example, we get an error:

"Invalid object name 'generate_series'"

Also, we then can't use CTE in Synapse either:
"Recursive CTEs are unsupported in this version of Synapse SQL."

This works in SQL Server Dev (On-Premise)

```
DECLARE @StartOfYear datetime = DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0));

SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, [value], @StartOfYear) AS [DATE_TIME]
FROM
    GENERATE_SERIES(1,
                    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartOfYear,
                        DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())+1,1,1)
                    )
                )
```

Msg 8768, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Recursive CTEs are unsupported in this version of Synapse SQL.

Answer (score 0):

`GENERATE_SERIES` function and recursive CTEs are not supported in Azure Synapse Analytics. To achieve the same result, you can use a WHILE loop in synapse sql.

**Code:**

```sql
DECLARE @StartOfYear datetime = DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0));
DECLARE @EndOfYear datetime = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())+1,1,1);
DECLARE @Counter int = 1;

CREATE TABLE #TempTable ([DATE_TIME] datetime);

WHILE DATEADD(MINUTE, @Counter, @StartOfYear) < @EndOfYear
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #TempTable ([DATE_TIME])
    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, @Counter, @StartOfYear);
    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
END;

SELECT [DATE_TIME] FROM #TempTable;
```

This creates a temporary table called #TempTable, insert the datetime values generated by the WHILE loop into the table, and then select all the rows from the table.

This code is tested with sample value for **start date='2023-01-01 23:50:00.000'** and **end date = '2023-01-02'** in synapse sql ; date values are generated as in below image.

[image: img1]